# Twilio for Python installation errror (Win10)

Tags: python, twilio

I successfully added `python` to my PATH. I found these instructions on https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install#installation.

I get the following error when I try to run the following command on my Command Prompt :

`python setup.py install`

**Error :**

```
C:\Python27>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open('twilio/version.py') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'twilio/version.py'
```

I also took out the `setup.py` file from the twilio folder and placed it into `C:\Python27` directory.

Why is this error occuring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to install it via pip:

```
pip install twilio
```

If you must install it from source, first unpack the source code from the zip archive. Then locate the `setup.py` file. You need to run it in the same directory. So for example, if you unpacked twilio to `D:\twilio` and your setup file path is `D:\twilio\setup.py`, you first need to change directory to there.

```
cd D:\twilio\setup.py
python setup.py install
```

Looks like you tried to copy the `setup.py` file to your Python installation folder and tried to run it from there. That will not work since the setup file depends on other files in that unpacked source directory.

Comment: Still doesn't work! I did this : `C:\Python27\twilio-twilio-python-5.1.0-0-g0e9e095>python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh There is no `setup.py` file in there, please locate it first.

Comment: I am sure I have that file in the directort. Can the python setup and the twilio's unzipped folder be in different places ?

Comment: `can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` - I don't think it was in the directory.

Comment: There was another sub folder in which the setup file was. Foolish of me. Thank you for helping!